# React Redux Store Updates - Changes Don't Update Component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to Redux, using it with React, and am in need of some help.  I have a menu that when a menu item is clicked, another component needs to update some copy.  I'm able to dispatch an action and have the store update.  However, I can't get the child component (HeroText) to render the new store value in the store.subscribe method when the store values change.  Please help and thanks!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import HeroText from "../presentational/HeroText.jsx";
import bgImage from "../../../images/forest_fog.jpg";
import AnantaNavbar from "../presentational/AnantaNavbar.jsx";
import '../../../scss/hero.scss';
import store from '../../store/index';
import { connect } from "react-redux";


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        contact: state.contact,
        heroText: state.heroText
    }
}

class HeroContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);

    this.state = store.getState();

    store.subscribe(() => {
        console.log(store.getState().heroText);
        this.setState({
            heroText: store.getState().heroText,
        })
    })
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
        <div id="hero-container" style={{backgroundImage: ("url(" + bgImage + ")") || ""}}>
            <div className="container">
                <HeroText text={this.props.heroText}>
                    Welcome back {this.props.contact.full_name}
                </HeroText>

                <AnantaNavbar></AnantaNavbar>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HeroContainer);
```

**UPDATE**
Below is my parent App Container with Provider

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand, NavbarNav, NavbarToggler, Collapse, NavItem, NavLink, Dropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import LoginContainer from '../../../js/components/container/LoginContainer.jsx';
import DashboardContainer from '../../../js/components/container/DashboardContainer.jsx';
import HomeContainer from '../../../js/components/container/DashboardContainer.jsx';
import ProfileContainer from '../../../js/components/container/ProfileContainer.jsx';
import HeroContainer from "./HeroContainer.jsx";
import '../../../scss/globals.scss';
import logo from '../../../images/logo1.png';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../../store/index';

const Router = () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LoginContainer} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
            <Route exact path="/home" component={HomeContainer} />
            <React.Fragment>
                <HeroContainer />
                <Route path="/dashboard" component={DashboardContainer} />
                <Route path="/profile" component={ProfileContainer} />
            </React.Fragment>
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
);

class AppContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state = {

    };
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {

  }

  render()
  {
    return (
        <div>
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Router></Router>
            </Provider>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AppContainer;
```

The default heroText in the store says "DASHBOARD".  When a menu item is clicked, in this case a link to /profile, the heroText should update to "PROFILE" after updating the store.

[image]

You can see in the console that the store is changing, but the "DASHBOARD" copy is not reflecting.

**RESOLVED**
I got this working with the code below.  Thanks for all the help!

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import HeroText from "../presentational/HeroText.jsx";
import bgImage from "../../../images/forest_fog.jpg";
import AnantaNavbar from "../presentational/AnantaNavbar.jsx";
import '../../../scss/hero.scss';
import store from '../../store/index';
import { connect } from "react-redux";


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        contact: state.contact,
        heroText: state.heroText
    }
}

class HeroContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
        <div id="hero-container" style={{backgroundImage: ("url(" + bgImage + ")") || ""}}>
            <div className="container">
                <HeroText text={store.getState().heroText}>
                    Welcome back {store.getState().contact.full_name}
                </HeroText>

                <AnantaNavbar></AnantaNavbar>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HeroContainer);
```

Comment: You're using `subscribe` when Connect already does this for you, also you're using `props.heroText` when you're storing it on `state`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to get state from Redux, there's no pointing in keeping it in local state. Plus, you don't need to use `store.getState`, `connect` already does that for you.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    contact: state.contact,
    heroText: state.heroText
  }
}

class HeroContainer extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="hero-container" style={{backgroundImage: ("url(" + bgImage + ")") || ""}}>
        <div className="container">
          <HeroText text={this.props.heroText}>
            Welcome back {this.props.contact.full_name}
          </HeroText>

          <AnantaNavbar></AnantaNavbar>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HeroContainer);
```

You also need to make sure that your app is wrapped in a provider, like this:

```
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I do have Provider.  Please see my updates above.  I have it wrapped around react router.  I also tried your exact code above and it is still not working.

Comment: A component could store ephimeral data in its own state and shared data in Redux, is perfectly legit to use both. What is wrong is inherit local state from global state, instead of usining it directly.

Comment: @MosèRaguzzini I guess I should rephrase. I wasn't saying that components shouldn't have state, just that in this case the user is trying to get the state from Redux, so there's no point in copying to local state.

Comment: Mose, instead of using this.props.heroText in my render() method, I should just store.getState().heroText instead and then take out my local state object?